# Dart 2.7 migration for typedef with Null type parameter

Tags: dart, typedef

I'm trying to migrate some old dart 1.25 code to 2.7 on windows.
I face some errors and I don't understand how to fix these.

The code used some Null type parameters in a typedef like this :

```
typedef dynamic PropertyGetter(Null object);
```

I don't understand exactly why this was coded like this, but it worked on 1.25.
This typedef was use to get a property on an any passed type of object which may be Null I suppose.
I also suppose the Null type parameter had his own reason to be there.

But now, with dart 2.7, when executing the code I've got errors like this :

```
type 'XXXType' is not a subtype of type 'Null'
```

Any idea how the typedef code can be fixed ?

--- Edit 1 ---

Here is a test case to experiment with the problem :

```
typedef int PropertyGetter(Null object);

void main() {
  testTypedef(test1, 2);
  testTypedef(test2, 'foo');
}

void testTypedef(PropertyGetter pg, param){
  pg(param);
}

int test1(int val) {
  print('val:$val');
  return val;
}

int test2(String val) {
  print('val:$val');
  return 0;
}
```

console error message :

```
Unhandled exception:
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'Null'
```

Comment: What is the issue: Assigning a function to that type, and if so what is the type of the function, or invoking a function with static type `PropertyGetter`. If the latter, then cast the function to the actual type of the function being called, if you know it, or to `Function` before calling it

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly don't want to be using `Null` as a type here as a parameter of type `Null` can only accept `null` as an argument which is pretty useless.

If you're looking to define a typedef for a function that can take in any object, you should either use `dynamic` or `Object` as the type. However, if you use `Object`, you'll need to know what type to cast the object to before you can access any properties of the underlying object. I'd recommend using `dynamic` if you're just looking for a quick fix.